# WSO2 Add BAM Profile in ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam, wso2-esb

We're having troubles trying to add BAM Profiles to ESB following the manual:

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM201/Setting+up+BAM+Mediator#SettingupBAMMediator-ConfigureBAMServerProfilesandStreams

BAM 2.0.1 (latest version)

ESB 4.5.1 (latest version)

p2-repo from http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/p2-repo.zip (15-01-2013)

It works if you do it with both WSO2-servers in a single host, but it doesn't if ESB and BAM are running in separate hosts.
No logs or traffic found outgoing or incoming through port 7611.

The BAM thrift port 7611 is open and listening in BAM host, and is reachable from ESB port.

Details follows:

```
# uname -a
Linux ESBHOST 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Nov 9 08:03:13 EST 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# java -version
java version "1.7.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_11-b21)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)

# /opt/esb_default/bin/wso2server.sh version
WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus v4.5.1
WSO2 Carbon Framework v4.0.2

# nc -zv BAMHOST 7611
Connection to BAMHOST 7611 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

Any clue how to find the problem or where to start to solve it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved:

Even if you don't want to use secure connection, the port 7711 MUST be reachable and WILL BE USED.
Also while 7611 is listening in ALL the IP addresses of the BAM server, 7711 is only listening in the configured management IP.

Since this two features are not documented (yet), it's worthy to mention here for other people that could face a similar issue.
Thanks to WSO2 team for the support.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you enter the **BAM server**'s IP address when creating the **BAM Server Profile** in the UI. And also make sure you update **BAM Server Profile** information correctly in the ESB's mediator if you have changed some such information from **BAM Server Profile** UI. You have to manually update the mediation sequence after you have done it.

Comment: Hi Maninda, 

We have entered the BAM host IP correctly. Also we have unchecked the enable security checkbox to point to the port 7611.

We can verify From the ESB host using netcat that the IP and port we are entering are ok, open and listening.

The "test server" button fails "BAM Server cannot be connected!" then we can't move forward to create mediation sequences in this environment. There is no logs in ESB to trace the error.

Perhaps there is a feature that need to be installed that is not documented in the mentioned WSO2 page?
Thanks in advance again.

Comment: In development environment we use Java 1.6. Here you are using Java 1.7. I wonder whether there it has some effect. There are no other features to be installed other than the BAM Mediator Aggregate feature. If the "test server" button fails I have confidence to say this is a connection related problem. Better to check your firewall.

Comment: Seems there is a problem with BAM. I will look into this and let you know.

Comment: Thanks Maninda, 

BTW you can discard the firewall. As I've mentioned and also shown in the info, we have checked the port is reachable from the ESB host (nc -zv BAMHOST 7611). 

**Unless there is another port(s) being used in the thrift communication.** If it's the case let me know and we can check that too.