# Integration between WSO2 ESB 4.8.0 and WSO2 BAM 2.4.0 with changed ports

Tags: cassandra, wso2, thrift, wso2-esb

I am running ESB (port offset 0) and BAM (port offset +2) over same Server and 
I am facing error when send stream to BAM from ESB using BAM mediator.

Error in ESB when calling proxy (with BAM mediator):

```
[2014-03-20 23:02:21,234] ERROR - AsyncDataPublisher Error while connection to event receiver
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.exception.AgentException: Cannot borrow client for TCP,10.10.10.24:7713,TCP,10.10.10.24:7713
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.publisher.authenticator.AgentAuthenticator.connect(AgentAuthenticator.java:58)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.DataPublisher.start(DataPublisher.java:273)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.DataPublisher.<init>(DataPublisher.java:211)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.DataPublisher.<init>(DataPublisher.java:112)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.AsyncDataPublisher$ReceiverConnectionWorker.run(AsyncDataPublisher.java:784)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.exception.AuthenticationException: Thrift Authentication Exception
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.publisher.authenticator.ThriftAgentAuthenticator.connect(ThriftAgentAuthenticator.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.publisher.authenticator.AgentAuthenticator.connect(AgentAuthenticator.java:51)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: ThriftAuthenticationException(message:wrong userName or password)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$connect_result.read(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:1394)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$Client.recv_connect(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:88)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.secure.ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService$Client.connect(ThriftSecureEventTransmissionService.java:74)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.publisher.authenticator.ThriftAgentAuthenticator.connect(ThriftAgentAuthenticator.java:47)
    ... 11 more
[...]
[2014-03-21 01:58:14,955] ERROR - AsyncDataPublisher Reconnection failed for for ssl://10.10.10.24:7713
```

And error in BAM when receiving stream:

```
[2014-03-21 02:01:30,988]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.DataBridge} -  admin2 connected
[2014-03-21 02:01:31,242] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.authentication.Authenticator} -  wrong userName or password
```

I have updated `%BAM_HOME%/repository/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml` and  `%BAM_HOME%/repository/conf/etc/cassandra-auth.xml` with BAM's new admin credentials and port.

I can see that in BAM > Manage > Cassandra Keyspaces > List > Keyspace there is an empty space created.

User admin2 exits in BAM and has system admin role.
Any comment will be appreciated.

Comment: I have similar problem as this post [WSO2 Add BAM Profile in ESB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429628/wso2-add-bam-profile-in-esb) but with updated versions of ESB (4.8.0) and BAM (2.4.0). Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It works over Windows, JDK 7.x, WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 and WSO2 BAM 2.4.0.

Comment: It does not work in CentOS 6.4, JDK 7.x, ESB 4.8.1 and BAM 2.4.0.  Any idea?